# PHP code to insert data into mysql database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert data without refreshing the page using ajax and php, but the data is not getting inserted into the database.

### Here is my code

```
<?php
require 'validation_class.php';
$obj_menufacture = new Validation_Class();

if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $menufacture = $obj_menufacture->menufacture_add($_POST);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='js/jquery-3.0.0.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='form_id'>
            <form action='' method='post'>
                <input type='text' class='m_name' name='m_name' id='m_name' onchange="names('m_name')" onkeyup="names('m_name')"/>
                <span style='color:red;' id='m_name_error'></span>
                <input type="submit" name='btn' value="submit" id='save'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id='cool'></div>
        <style>
            .border_input{
                border-color:red;
            }
            .border_input1{
                border-color:green;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#save').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var m_name = $.trim($('#m_name').val());
                    var dataString = 'name='+ m_name;
                    if (m_name === '') {
                        if (m_name == '') {
                            $('#m_name_error').html('Please enter your name');
                            $('#m_name').addClass('border_input');

                        }
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'validation.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data:dataString,
                            success: function () {
                                $("#form_id").slideUp("slow");

                            }
                        });
                    }

                });

            });

            function names(id) {
                var val = $.trim($('#' + id).val());
                if (val === '') {
                    $('#' + id + '_error').html('');
                    $('#' + id).addClass('border_input');
                } else {
                    $('#' + id + '_error').html('');
                    $('#' + id).addClass('border_input1');
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Here is my insert code

```
<?php

class Validation_Class{

    public $link;

    public function __construct() {
        $HOST = "localhost";
        $USER = "root";
        $PASS = "";
        $DATABASE = "store";
        $this->link = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASS, $DATABASE);
        if (!$this->link) {
            die('database query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
        }
    }

    public function menufacture_add($data) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO menufacture(m_name)VALUES('$data[m_name]')";
        if (mysqli_query($this->link, $sql)) {
            $menufacture = "Menufacture insert successfully";
            return $menufacture;
        } else {
            die('menufacruere query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
        }
    }


}
```

please help me what can i do to solve this

Comment: Read what is ajax. Pleas do some make use of google to search and you will get primary information on what ever technology you are planning to work. I dont think this should be a write me code kind of forum. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Do you get any errors? Enable error-reporting in PHP `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check your console for JS errors.

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Have you done a `var_dump($data)` to see what it actually contains? What steps have you taken to debug this yourself?

Comment: Btw... You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: You do realize that you're executing your query twice? First in your `if`-statement condition (`if (mysqli_query($this->link, $sql))`) and then again if that first query returns true.

Comment: You should also handle potential db-errors with: `mysqli_error()`. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You're sending the `m_name` field as `name` in your ajax request, but you're trying to get it with `m_name` in your PHP-code. You need to enable error reporting and display errors. This would definitively have given you an "undefined index"-error. There are just too many issues with your code.¨

Comment: Is that all your php code? I don't see you calling manufacture_add() anywhere

Comment: the menufacture_add($_POST) call at top of the page

Comment: I correct the ajax name and sql query but still it's not working

Comment: if I use submit function on jquery it work's..........but I want to use click function

Comment: Please some body give me a full code that insert data without page refresh with OOP MYSQLI PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form  name="signup" id="reg" action="" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' class='m_name' name='m_name' id='m_name' onchange="names('m_name')" onkeyup="names('m_name')"/>
    <span style='color:red;' id='m_name_error'></span>
    <input type="submit" name='btn' value="submit" id='save'/>
</form>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $("#save").submit(function () {
                    var form_data = $('#reg').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'setting.php',
                        data: $('#reg').serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Data save Successfully');
                        }, error: function () {
                            alert('Some Internal Error.');
                        }
                    });
                });`
            </script>
```

**settting.php**

```
            <?php

            include("db_connection.php"); // include connection file
            if(isset($_POST)) {
            $fname = $_POST['m_name'];
            $insert = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`column_name`)VALUES('".$fname."')";
            $insertion = mysqli_query($conn, $insert); 
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: I want to do this with click function

Comment: Please some body give me a full code that insert data without page refresh with OOP MYSQLI PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
              $("#save").on("click", function () {
              var form_data = $('#reg').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",

                 url:'setting.php',
                data: $('#reg').serialize(),

                success: function(data){

                  alert("Data save Successfully");  

                },error: function () {
                alert('Some Internal Error.');
            }
          });

            });
```

Comment: Try this. Replace only replace script

Comment: I use your code but data is not inserted in data base

Comment: Please post you code.And review once again id name all place are same

Comment: give form id="reg" and try again

Comment: Please some body give me a full code that insert data without page refresh with OOP MYSQLI PHP